# Multiprocessing with Python from a text file

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask, ncbi

I'm trying to extract the data for given set of PMID from a text file, how can I speed up the process, Can someone help with how to implement multiprocessing, thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.environ['NCBI_API_KEY'] = ""
import metapub


with open("pmid.txt", "r") as file:
    pmid = file.read().splitlines()

data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["PMID", "PMC", "DOI", "Year", "Title", "Authors",
                     "Journal", "Abstract", "Keywords", "Chemicals", "Mesh_Descriptors", "Mesh_Qualifiers", "URL"])
data['PMID'] = pmid
fetch = metapub.PubMedFetcher()
for i, row in data.iterrows():
    try:
        article = fetch.article_by_pmid(row["PMID"])
        data.iloc[i, 1] = article.pmc
        data.iloc[i, 2] = article.doi
        data.iloc[i, 3] = article.history['pubmed'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
        data.iloc[i, 4] = article.title
        data.iloc[i, 5] = article.authors
        data.iloc[i, 6] = article.journal
        data.iloc[i, 7] = article.abstract
        data.iloc[i, 8] = article.keywords
        data.iloc[i, 9] = list(map(lambda v: v["substance_name"], article.chemicals.values()))
        data.iloc[i, 10] = list(map(lambda v: v["descriptor_name"], article.mesh.values()))
        data.iloc[i, 11] = list(map(lambda v: v["qualifier_name"], article.mesh.values()))
        data.iloc[i, 12] = article.url
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(i)
            data.to_csv("myfile.csv", index = False)   
    except:
        pass
print('Finish')
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting the full csv to the same path every 1000 rows? That can’t help your performance

Comment: @MichaelDelgado: perhaps to get incremental updates, I've done something like this a few times to get an early peek into the compute results...

Comment: Sure, but if you’re trying to improve performance… :)

Comment: @Michael Delgado Maybe I can try to append the data by setting mode = "a"

Comment: What I’m getting at is… even according to the dask docs, the first step in speeding up your code with dask *is to speed up your code without dask*

Comment: I'll try to save it in a dictionary instead of a dataframe, I suppose that would improve the speed a little

Comment: @Mathew maybe. Or you could debug your workflow ahead of time on subsets of the data and then run the full thing without iteratively writing. You wouldn’t be able to do this iterative csv append with dask by the way so it’s best to get used to not doing this.

Comment: Dataframes are fine - I’m just talking about the to_csv part.

Comment: The way I’d tackle this with dask is to partition the dataframe into chunks with dask.dataframe.from_pandas and then call your current logic (without the csv write) using map_partitions. You’ll need a new function that can operate on blocks of rows, essentially your whole current workflow that will be called on subsets of the full dataframe. Then you can write the full result using dask.dataframe.to_csv

Comment: `fetch.article_by_pmid` takes ~600ms for me, is that about right?  if so that's the biggest bottleneck and you almost certainly want a caching layer in there.  `metapub` uses `eutils` which suggests it might do some caching, but doesn't actually work for me.  I'd suggest caching the response XML (i.e. `article.xml` as the constructor for `metapub.PubMedArticle` can parse this).  any complete answer for this would be enormous, I'd suggest posting a more specific question if/when you get stuck with this

Answer (score 1):

I got a bit carried away with this and ended up writing code to use a [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool) as this will be network bound so having multiple processes isn't going to help.

I've tried to put some comments and docstrings in, but it might be a bit fancier code than your question suggests you're used to.  Responses from PubMed are cached using [`sqlitedict`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/sqlitedict) which makes this mostly painless.

```
import csv
import logging
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from sys import stdin, stdout
from time import perf_counter
from typing import Iterator, List, Optional

from metapub import PubMedArticle, PubMedFetcher
from sqlitedict import SqliteDict

# shared by members of the ThreadPool 
article_cache = SqliteDict("pubmed_cache.db", "articles")
fetcher = PubMedFetcher()


def fetch_article(pmid: str) -> PubMedArticle:
    "call fetcher.article_by_pmid with lots of logging statements"
    # log as this is going to take a non-trivial amount of time
    logging.info("fetching article with pmid=%r", pmid)

    t0 = perf_counter()
    article = fetcher.article_by_pmid(pmid)
    dt = perf_counter() - t0
    logging.info("fetched pmid=%s in %.3fms", pmid, dt * 1000)

    # check if we got the right thing back
    if article.pmid != pmid:
        logging.warning("article with pmid=%r returned pmid=%r", pmid, article.pmid)

    return article


def fetch_article_cached(pmid: str) -> PubMedArticle:
    """cache XML of fetched articles so subsequent runs are faster.
    errors are returned as None
    """
    try:
        xml = article_cache[pmid]
    except KeyError:
        # cached failed, continue below with fetching
        pass
    else:
        # cache hit, parse it
        return PubMedArticle(xml)

    try:
        article = fetch_article(pmid)
    except Exception as err:
        logging.warning("error fetching pmid=%r: %s", pmid, err)
        article = None

    # save XML in cache for next time
    article_cache[pmid] = article.xml
    article_cache.commit()

    return article


def fetch_articles(
    pmids: List[str], *, processes: Optional[int] = None
) -> Iterator[PubMedArticle]:
    "use a threadpool to fetch articles from metapub in parallel, caching where possible"
    with ThreadPool(processes=processes) as pool:
        for article in pool.imap_unordered(fetch_article_cached, pmids):
            # couldn't be fetched
            if article is None:
                continue
            yield article


def main() -> None:
    "fetch articles by PMID from stdin and write to stdout in CSV format"
    pmids = stdin.read().split()

    out = csv.writer(stdout)
    first = True
    for article in fetch_articles(pmids, processes=6):
        row = dict(
            pmid=article.pmid,
            pmc=article.pmc,
            doi=article.doi,
            date=article.history["pubmed"],
            title=article.title,
            authors=article.authors,
            journal=article.journal,
            abstract=article.abstract,
            # keywords=article.keywords,
            chemicals=[v["substance_name"] for v in article.chemicals.values()],
            mesh_descriptors=[v["descriptor_name"] for v in article.mesh.values()],
            mesh_qualifiers=[v["qualifier_name"] for v in article.mesh.values()],
            url=article.url,
        )
        if first:
            out.writerow(row.keys())
            first = False
        out.writerow(row.values())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

I've been testing by running from the command line as:

```bash
echo 32257431 30849247 28302313 | python pubmed_article_fetcher.py > out.csv
```

But it could be run as follows to mirror the question's use of files:

```bash
env NCBI_API_KEY=xxx python pubmed_article_fetcher.py < pmid.txt > myfile.csv
```

It uses standard Unix pipes to read PMIDs from the `pmid.txt` file and write output to `myfile.csv`

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, is there a way to keep track of the records since I have around 8 million pmid's and also I'm running it in the screen detach mode. Previously I was using a simple counter function to print out after every 10000 records, maybe I'll try to use that inside the main function

Comment: @Mathew you could just run `wc -l` on the output file to see how many rows are in it.  a quick calculation suggests you'll be waiting more than a week if you're 10 API connections in parallel, so https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/download/ might be a better source for that much data.  as shown above, you can just pass the contents of an XML file to the `PubMedArticle`.